# Error in : Column indexes must be at most 6 if positive - Shiny App Error in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build shiny app using `shiny` library and `gapminder` as my dataset. I am building small app, where user can select specific continent from side panel and the histogram on population vs year of the selected continent gets displayed on the mainpanel of shiny App.

I am using below code to generate the histogram. However, when I run the below code I am getting an error in R that say's

> Column indexes must be 6 if positive...

I am not sure what it means.Also, I have attached my expected output.

My Rcode:

```
library(shiny)
library(gapminder)

ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Population Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'cont',
                label = "Select Continent:",
                choices = gapminder$continent),
    selectInput(inputId = 'year',
                label = "Select Year:",
                choices = gapminder$year)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    paste('Aggregate population by year'),
   textOutput("txtoutput"),
   plotOutput("continentplot")
  )
)
)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$txtoutput<-renderText({
    paste(input$cont)
  })
  output$continentplot<-renderPlot({
    req(gapminder$year)
  hist(gapminder[gapminder$pop])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Error:

```
warning: Error in : Column indexes must be at most 6 if positive, not 8425333, 9240934, 10267083, 11537966, 13079460, 14880372, 12881816, 13867957, 16317921, 22227415, 25268405, 31889923, 1282697, 1476505, 1728137, 1984060, 2263554, 2509048, 2780097, 3075321, 3326498, 3428038, 3508512, 3600523, 9279525, 10270856, 11000948, 12760499, 14760787, 17152804, 20033753, 23254956, 26298373, 29072015, 31287142, 33333216, 4232095, 4561361, 4826015, 5247469, 5894858, 6162675, 7016384, 7874230, 8735988, 9875024, 10866106, 12420476, 17876956, 19610538, 21283783, 22934225, 24779799, 26983828, 29341374, 31620918, 33958947, 36203463, 38331121, 40301927, 8691212, 9712569, 10794968, 11872264, 13177000, 14074100, 15184200, 16257249, 17481977, 18565243, 19546792, 20434176, 6927772, 6965860, 7129864, 7376998, 7544201, 7568430, 7574613, 7578903, 7914969, 8069876, 8148312, 8199783, 120447, 138655, 171863, 202182, 230800, 297410, 377967, 454612, 529491, 598561, 656397, 708573, 46886859, 51365468, 56839289, 62821884, 70 [... truncated]
  179: <Anonymous>
Warning: Error in : Column indexes must be at most 6 if positive, not 8425333, 9240934, 10267083, 11537966, 13079460, 14880372, 12881816, 13867957, 16317921, 22227415, 25268405, 31889923, 1282697, 1476505, 1728137, 1984060, 2263554, 2509048, 2780097, 3075321, 3326498, 3428038, 3508512, 3600523, 9279525, 10270856, 11000948, 12760499, 14760787, 17152804, 20033753, 23254956, 26298373, 29072015, 31287142, 33333216, 4232095, 4561361, 4826015, 5247469, 5894858, 6162675, 7016384, 7874230, 8735988, 9875024, 10866106, 12420476, 17876956, 19610538, 21283783, 22934225, 24779799, 26983828, 29341374, 31620918, 33958947, 36203463, 38331121, 40301927, 8691212, 9712569, 10794968, 11872264, 13177000, 14074100, 15184200, 16257249, 17481977, 18565243, 19546792, 20434176, 6927772, 6965860, 7129864, 7376998, 7544201, 7568430, 7574613, 7578903, 7914969, 8069876, 8148312, 8199783, 120447, 138655, 171863, 202182, 230800, 297410, 377967, 454612, 529491, 598561, 656397, 708573, 46886859, 51365468, 56839289, 62821884, 70 [... truncated]
  179: <Anonymous>
```

**Expected output:**

[image]

I am new to R and Shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `req(gapminder$year)` makes continue the code because `gapminder$year` is not `NULL`. You need to use `input$year`. Also, you need to require that a continent is specified: `req(gapminder$continent)`
2. You need another `req` before pasting `textOuput` because `input$cont` is empty at the beginning
3. To plot a basic histogram you only can pass the vector of data to plot (`pop`) First, for sure, you need to filter for your year and continent selected

library(shiny)

library(gapminder)

library(dplyr)

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Population Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'cont',
                label = "Select Continent:",
                choices = gapminder$continent),
    selectInput(inputId = 'year',
                label = "Select Year:",
                choices = gapminder$year)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    paste('Aggregate population by year'),
    textOutput("txtoutput"),
    plotOutput("continentplot")
  )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$txtoutput<-renderText({
    req(input$cont)
    paste(input$cont)
  })
  output$continentplot<-renderPlot({
    req(input$year)
    req(input$cont)
    dataHist <- gapminder %>% 
      filter(continent==input$cont) %>% 
      filter(year==as.integer(input$year)) %>%
      select(pop)
    hist(dataHist$pop)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

For your second question, you can use this code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Population Analysis"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = 'cont',
                label = "Select Continent:",
                choices = gapminder$continent)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    paste('Aggregate population by year'),
    textOutput("txtoutput"),
    plotOutput("continentplot")
  )
  )
)

server<-function(input,output){
  output$txtoutput<-renderText({
    req(input$cont)
    paste(input$cont)
  })
  output$continentplot<-renderPlot({
    req(input$cont)
    dataHist <- gapminder %>% 
      filter(continent==input$cont)  %>%
      group_by(year)%>%
      select(pop,year)

    ggplot(data=dataHist, aes(x=year, y=pop)) + 
      labs(y="Population") +
      geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="purple") + 
      scale_x_continuous(name ="Year",breaks = seq(1952,2007,5))+
      theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "plum1",
                                        colour = "plum1",
                                        size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "white"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "white")
      )

  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Yo can play with the `colour` and `fill` parameters (http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour) to customize your plot! 
Best!

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Currently, the plot is displaying, histogram of selected continent and selected year. However, I would like to display barplot such that pop growth by all years of  selected continent is displayed.

Comment: @LocoGris..essentially what I want to do is ..I would like to select the continent, and It should display me total population of entire continent on Y axis and Year on X-axis.

Comment: Then you do not need to select a Year, dont you? Because you are going to show all

Comment: @LocoGris..Yes, correct..I tried that too.. but it's giving me an error saying "invalid number of 'breaks'. Also, updated expected output. Thanks!